# symfony2 - DBAL custom "model" layer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In the process of writing a symfony2 application, I need to write a custom model layer for all the database interactions, and I'd like to use Doctrine DBAL, not the full ORM. This because I didn't design the database and a set of predefined queries must be used.

I get that I can just call a service for the DBAL connection from the controller, like:

```
$results = $this->get('my_service')->someMethod();
```

having defined the service as:

*src/Acme/BundleName/Resources/config/services.yml*

```
services:
  my_service:
  class:  Acme\BundleName\Entity\BaseEntity
  arguments:  [@database_connection]
```

*src/Acme/BundleName/Entity/BaseEntity.php*

```
namespace Acme\BundleName\Entity;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class BaseEntity
{
  private $connection;

  public function __construct(Connection $dbalConnection)  {
      $this->connection = $dbalConnection;    
 }

 public function someMethod(){
   //method logic
 }
```

}

Now, how can I call that service from my custom model class, so I can use the dbal connection for executing raw slq?

I also get that I could define every class as a service that would have the dbal connection injected, but this would lead me to have dozens of defined services (one for each model class) only for sharing the dbal connection.

Ideally I would like to have my classes mapping the database tables, with custom logic, like many other frameworks do. I also know that I can define custom "Repository" in Doctrine orm, but I need to stick with only the DBAL layer.

Comment: You can use and DBAL and Doctrine repositories in Symfony, so what is your question?

Comment: How can I get a DBAL connection from a custom class (my model classes)?

Comment: You mean `custom class` is a service?

Comment: I actually don't know if it should be a service or not, I am looking for a way to have the DBAL connection in my custom model classes and I thought defining it into a service was a good approach, but I can get that service (the dbal connection service) only from a Controller class.

Comment: But you already inject DBAL to service with `arguments:  [@database_connection]`. This is a solution what you need. So use `$this->connection` in this service

Comment: It's true. But I have all the classes in my model layer that should access to that dbal connection, for performing queries, is there any way I can do that? For now I can access that service only from a Controller class.

Comment: In this way you can get access to this service from other services, controllers or templates. Not from repositories or entities. Is this that you need?

Comment: My model classes aren't entities nor repositories, they're just plain classes autoloaded in the framework. I understand that I could turn those classes into services, that can access to the dbal service, but that would lead me to define as many services as model classes I have, and I wonder if there's a better way to do that.

Comment: Why are you won't to use native Doctrine Repositories as models?

Comment: Because I don't need an ORM, I only want to get data from the database, without mapping tables into objects. DBAL is all the abstraction I need.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think You need to create a `service`, inject in it Doctrine `DBAL` dependency, and load and work with your models via this service

```
public function someMethod(){
   //load the model
   $model = new MyModel();
   // Then get data from DB and fetch them to model

   //other method logic
   return $model;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I have a service injected with DBAL.
I just don't see how I can interact with my model classes

Comment: Check update. Try to use something like in my example. But if you do not have any ideas with it realization or badly understand how it must work, maybe you better need to use Doctrine first?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do understand how a service works. I don't understand how to make my model classes as services without declaring one service per model. If you notice, in your solution, there's an hardcoded class instantiation, it was what i was trying to avoid, but at this point I think it's not possible.

Comment: You can config `composer` for dynamic loading your model classes from dir, and you don't need to use `require` or `include`